# Rails 3.2 Template error in engine test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

I create simple engine. All works fine, but when i try to write functiontal test for engine's controller a get error like this:

```
3) Error:
test_should_get_new(Supportilla::SessionsControllerTest):
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {}
```

My test file test/functional/supportilla/sessions_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

module Supportilla
  class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase   
    test "should get new" do
      get "new", use_route: "supportilla"
      assert_response :success
    end

    test "should get create" do
      post :create, { session: { username: "test", password: "123"},
        use_route: :supportilla }
      assert_response :success
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

And engine mounted in test/dummy/config/routes.rb:

```
mount Supportilla::Engine => "/supportilla"
```

Rake routes:

```
Routes for Supportilla::Engine:
    signin GET    /signin(.:format)             supportilla/sessions#new
   signout GET    /signout(.:format)            supportilla/sessions#destroy
           POST   /signin(.:format)             supportilla/sessions#create
       ...
```

I'm very confused and hope for your help.